# Select Closest span

Tags: jquery

Here is my HTML code

```
                <span class="xxt" style="">Hide Me</span>
                <div><br/></div>
                <div></div>
                <span style="">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="">
                                <div></div>
                                <input type="radio" class="a">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </span>

                <span class="xxt" style="">Hide Me</span>
                <div><br/></div>
                <div></div>
                <span style="">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="">
                                <div></div>
                                <input type="radio" class="a">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </span>
```

I am trying to access the closest span element with class "xxt" which is nearer to the parent span of the changed radio button.
Here is my code

```
       $('.a').live('change',function()
         {
            $(this).parents('span').closest('.xxt').addClass('DestQID');
            $('.DestQID').hide();
         });
```

Here is [my test jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YJVbb/1/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.a').live('change',function()
{
    $(this).closest('span').prevAll('.xxt:first').addClass('DestQID');
    $('.DestQID').hide();
});
```

Comment: So .closest("span") does the same thing as .parents('span:first'). That's cool, I'll have to remember that one :)